# Anaconda does not use package from activated environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have a `conda` environment, in a bash terminal, with an Intel Python Distribution interpreter. However, when importing packages, they are imported from what looks to be the user directory of the system default Python, not the environment. Take a look at the version discrepancy and the `__spec__` origin of the `pandas` package.

```
 ~  $  conda activate idp
 ~  $  which python
~/anaconda3/envs/idp/bin/python
 ~  $  python
Python 3.6.8 |Intel Corporation| (default, Mar  1 2019, 00:10:45) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.22.0'
>>> pandas.__spec__
ModuleSpec(name='pandas', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f509e184ba8>, origin='/home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas'])
>>> 
 ~  $  conda list | head -n 3
# packages in environment at /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/idp:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
 ~  $  conda list | grep pandas
pandas                    0.24.1                   py36_3    intel
 ~  $  conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/torstein/anaconda3
idp                   *  /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/idp
py36                     /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/py36
```

When using the `base` environment, this does NOT happen; packages (e.g. `pandas`) are imported from the correct path:

```
 ~  $  conda deactivate
 ~  $  conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/torstein/anaconda3
idp                      /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/idp
py36                     /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/py36

 ~  $  which python
~/anaconda3/bin/python
 ~  $  python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Oct  9 2018, 10:31:47) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
pan>>> pandas.__version__
'0.23.4'
>>> pandas.__spec__
ModuleSpec(name='pandas', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fad808a8e80>, origin='/home/torstein/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/home/torstein/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas'])
```

The relevant part of `.bashrc` (no anaconda explicitly set in path):

```
export PATH="/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/torstein/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/torstein/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/torstein/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/torstein/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Which yields these `$PATH`s, for the `base` and `idp` envs respectively:

```
 ~  $  echo $PATH
/home/torstein/anaconda3/bin:/home/torstein/anaconda3/condabin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/home/torstein/anaconda3/bin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/torstein/.local/bin:/home/torstein/bin
 ~  $  conda activate idp
 ~  $  echo $PATH
/home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/idp/bin:/home/torstein/anaconda3/condabin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/home/torstein/anaconda3/bin:/home/torstein/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/torstein/.local/bin:/home/torstein/bin
```

The `pandas` that I *do* want to import is located here, where it should be:

`/home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas`

Comment: @merv: Which paths should I exclude? And do I really need to create the whole conda environment from scratch or do you mean to set the path manually then try importing again? `/home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/` is not explicitly included in `$PATH`.

Comment: By the way do packages installed with anaconda's `pip` for the py36 environment end up in `/home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`? Because there is no system-wide python 3.6 installation (but there was once upon a time).

Comment: I'm assuming that the other Python 3.6 is coming from `/home/torstein/.local/bin`, based on the site packages. I'd recreate the whole thing - most of the packages should be cached, so it shouldn't take long.  However, you can try it without if you'd like; though, I expect that the dependency resolver has already set something in the **idp** env that points to the wrong `site-packages`.

Comment: *there is no system-wide python 3.6 installation* oh, then you should probably delete that `/home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` directory (back it up first though just in case).  No, `pip` in a Conda env should still be keeping within the env.  Do you have `PYTHONPATH` set (when not in an activated env)?

Comment: @merv: `PYTHONPATH` is not set either in `base` or `idp`. I don't know if it's set *before* conda runs the automatic `PATH` manipulation upon terminal startup. Deleting (or renaming) `/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` did the trick. Creating a new env was not necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Diagnosis

There appears to be (or have been) another Python 3.6 in the `PATH`, and I suspect that somehow the Conda dependency resolver ended up resolving some packages to this alternative `site-packages` and inadvertently including this directory in `sys.path`.  This appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6018).

### Evidence

The reason I believe this is because the `pandas` module is being loaded from here:

> /home/torstein/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas

If you check in Python

```
import sys

sys.path
```

I expect that this should show the above directory.

Since it was reported that `PYTHONPATH` is empty (as it should be!), that can't be responsible for this misloading, hence I think it was Conda that somehow configured the env this way.

Also, the fact that your Python 3.7 env is unaffected is likely because you can't load modules across different minor versions.

### Immediate Solution

Somehow you need to get rid of that dependency.  There are a few things to try

1. Remove that `/home/torstein/.local/` from your `PATH`. This could cause other issues though. Presumably you have it in `PATH` because you have other non-development things in there.
2. Dump specifically that `site-packages` directory. In comments, it was stated that this is residual from a global Python installation no longer in use, so it seems like a good thing to just get rid of.  Do back it up, though, in case there are other dependencies on it.
3. Clear this path from `sys.path` before importing modules. Not sure of a clean way to do this.

Personally, I'd want to delete it and create new envs. It can be hard to know how tied into this directory you are, so I'd be wary of assuming that other packages don't somehow have hidden dependencies on what is in there.

### Long-Term Workaround

The recommended workaround from [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6018) is to add the following environment variable,

```
export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=True
```

which prevents Conda from loading other local `site-packages` directories. With this, you shouldn't have encountered the problem in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

Solution is: in anaconda\env\xyz (as well as in other implementations), set the path environment variable to the directory where 'python.exe' is installed.

As a default, the python.exe file in anaconda is in:

```
c:\.....\anaconda\env\xyz
```

after you do that, obviously, the python command works, in my case, yielding the following.

```
python
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.2.0. (64|bit)|(default, Nov 7 2015), etc, etc
```

Comment: The Python interpreter is the correct one as you can see in the post.

Comment: This is contrary to recommended practice. Since Conda v.4.4 no manual manipulation of `PATH` should be done (see [release notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).