# Downgraded library does not work in the conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, conda, virtual-environment

I've downgraded numpy from 1.16.1 to 1.15.1 in my conda environment (fastai_07), but I'm still getting the numpy 1.16.1:

```
(fastai_07) robin@xps:~/github/fastai$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.16.1'
```

That's what I did:

```
(fastai_07) robin@xps:~/github/fastai$ conda install numpy=1.15.1
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/robin/anaconda3/envs/fastai_07

  added / updated specs:
    - numpy=1.15.1


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    numpy-1.15.1               |   py36h3b04361_0          37 KB
    numpy-base-1.15.1          |   py36h81de0dd_0         4.2 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.2 MB

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  spacy              fastai::spacy-2.0.18-py36hf484d3e_1000 --> pkgs/main::spacy-2.0.16-py36h962f231_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  mkl                                            2019.3-199 --> 2018.0.3-1
  mkl_fft                             1.0.10-py36ha843d7b_0 --> 1.0.6-py36h7dd41cf_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.2-py36hd81dba3_0 --> 1.0.1-py36h4414c95_1
  numexpr                              2.6.9-py36h9e4a6bb_0 --> 2.6.8-py36hd89afb7_0
  numpy                               1.16.2-py36h7e9f1db_0 --> 1.15.1-py36h3b04361_0
  numpy-base                          1.16.2-py36hde5b4d6_0 --> 1.15.1-py36h81de0dd_0
  scipy                                1.2.1-py36h7c811a0_0 --> 1.1.0-py36hfa4b5c9_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
numpy-base-1.15.1    | 4.2 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
numpy-1.15.1         | 37 KB     | ################################################################################################################################################################# | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

which python, gives:

```
(fastai_07) robin@xps:~/github/fastai$ which python
/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/fastai_07/bin/python
```

and conda list:

```
(fastai_07) robin@xps:~/github/fastai$ conda list
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# packages in environment at /home/robin/anaconda3/envs/fastai_07:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
attrs                     19.1.0                   py36_1  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0  
backports                 1.0                      py36_1  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py36_0  
bcolz                     1.2.1            py36h04863e7_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py36_0  
blosc                     1.15.0               hd408876_0  
bokeh                     1.0.4                    py36_0  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5  
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py36_0  
cffi                      1.12.2           py36h2e261b9_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py36_1  
click                     7.0                      py36_0  
cliff                     2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cloudpickle               0.8.0                    py36_0  
cmd2                      0.9.11                   pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
configparser              3.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              2.6.1            py36h1ba5d50_0  
cssselect                 1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cuda90                    1.0                  h6433d27_0    pytorch
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0  
cudnn                     7.3.1                cuda10.0_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
cymem                     2.0.2            py36hfd86e86_0  
cython                    0.29.6           py36he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h14c3975_1  
dask                      1.1.4                    py36_1  
dask-core                 1.1.4                    py36_1  
dbus                      1.13.6               h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.0                    py36_1  
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py36_1  
descartes                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.2.9                    py36_0  
distributed               1.26.0                   py36_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
feather-format            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.8                      py36_0  
importlib_metadata        0.8                      py36_0  
intel-openmp              2019.3                      199  
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py36h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.4.0            py36h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py36_0  
isoweek                   1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.13.3                   py36_0  
jinja2                    2.10                     py36_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py36_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py36_0  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0  
kaggle-cli                0.12.13                  pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36hf484d3e_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libiconv                  1.15                 h63c8f33_5  
libpng                    1.6.36               hbc83047_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libtiff                   4.0.10               h2733197_2  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                he19cac6_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py36_1  
lxml                      4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mechanicalsoup            0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h7b6447c_0  
mizani                    0.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py36h7dd41cf_0  
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h4414c95_1  
msgpack-numpy             0.4.3.2                  py36_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py36hfd86e86_1  
murmurhash                1.0.2            py36he6710b0_0  
nbconvert                 5.4.1                    py36_3  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py36_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
notebook                  5.7.8                    py36_0  
numexpr                   2.6.8            py36hd89afb7_0  
numpy                     1.15.1           py36h3b04361_0  
numpy-base                1.15.1           py36h81de0dd_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py36_0  
openssl                   1.1.1b               h7b6447c_1  
packaging                 19.0                     py36_0  
palettable                3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.24.2           py36he6710b0_0  
pandas-summary            0.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1  
parso                     0.3.4                    py36_0  
partd                     0.3.10                   py36_1  
path.py                   11.5.0                   py36_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py36_0  
pbr                       5.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pdpbox                    0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0  
pillow                    5.4.1            py36h34e0f95_0  
pip                       19.0.3                   py36_0  
plac                      0.9.6                    py36_0  
plotnine                  0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
preshed                   2.0.1            py36he6710b0_0  
prettytable               0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
progressbar2              3.34.3                   pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.6.0                    py36_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py36_0  
psutil                    5.6.1            py36h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py36_0  
pyarrow                   0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_0  
pygments                  2.3.1                    py36_0  
pyhamcrest                1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.3.1                    py36_0  
pyperclip                 1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h05f1152_2  
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py36h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0  
pytables                  3.5.1            py36h71ec239_0  
python                    3.6.8                h0371630_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py36_0  
python-graphviz           0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python-utils              2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   0.3.1           py36_cuda9.0.176_cudnn7.0.5_2  [cuda90]  pytorch
pytz                      2018.9                   py36_0  
pyyaml                    5.1              py36h7b6447c_0  
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py36he6710b0_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py36_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
regex                     2018.01.10      py36h14c3975_1000    fastai
requests                  2.21.0                   py36_0  
scikit-learn              0.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-misc               0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0            py36hd20e5f9_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py36_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0  
setuptools                40.8.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
sip                       4.19.8           py36hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py36_0  
sklearn-pandas            1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py36_0  
spacy                     2.0.16           py36h962f231_0  
sqlite                    3.27.2               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h035aef0_0  
stevedore                 1.30.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tblib                     1.3.2                    py36_0  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
testfixtures              6.6.0                      py_0  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py36_0  
thinc                     6.12.1          py36h637b7d7_1000    fastai
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0  
torchtext                 0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.1.9                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   4.5.3                    py36_0  
tqdm                      4.31.1                   py36_1  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
ujson                     1.35             py36h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py36_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
wheel                     0.33.1                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36h14c3975_2  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zict                      0.1.4                    py36_0  
zipp                      0.3.3                    py36_1  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Could you please help me make the numpy 1.15.1 working for this environment?
*Please let me know if the provided information is sufficient.

EDIT: @merv:
after `pip install numpy=1.15.1`

```
(base) robin@xps:~$ conda activate fastai07
(fastai07) robin@xps:~$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__spec__
ModuleSpec(name='numpy', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb3a68cefd0>, origin='/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/fastai07/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/home/robin/anaconda3/envs/fastai07/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'])
```

I'm happy that it works now. Thanks!

Comment: You have packages mixed from several conda channels, and from pypi (meaning installed with `pip`). You should avoid that situation and use `conda` only if possible.
You can try to recreate the environment from scratch `conda create -n newenv --clone fastai_07`, but you will have to check whether pypi packages are ok.

Comment: I've tried `conda create -n newenv --clone fastai_07` and then `conda install numpy=1.15.1` after activating the `fastai_07` , but it didn't work. I'm not sure if you meant that. However, `pip install numpy=1.15.1` did the job. Based on your answer I didn't do it properly I guess. Do you know any good post about good practices. I'm new to that and I have hard time reading entire documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Some advises on using conda and pip [here](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).
You can still try `conda install numpy==1.15.1 --force-reinstall` (notice the `==`), or `conda remove numpy` and then reinstalling. But beware the last option will remove packages that depends on numpy, so you will have to reinstall them all (at least conda makes a list of removed packages so you will know precisely what to do).

Comment: @DexzMen I find it curious that, according to the installation plan, the NumPy version in your original environment was actually **1.6.2** and not **1.6.1**, which is what you show as importing.  I suspect your problem is related to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089352/anaconda-does-not-use-package-from-activated-environment). It would have been helpful for you to show us the output of `numpy.__spec__`, to show where it came from and not just version.

Comment: @FabienP thank you for your suggestion. I've added an edit.  I'm happy that for now everything is working. Thank You!

Comment: @DexzMen thanks. Unfortunately `__spec__` isn't so helpful now that NumPy is the correct one. However, checking the output of `import sys; sys.path` might still be useful and would indicate if there is still some non-Conda folder on your imports path.