# Why python import <package_name> checks wrong package location

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I have setup an Anaconda environment. then I have installed OpenCV4

[image]

as you can see the location of site-packages folder where OpenCV was installed

then when try to import cv2, python gives error indicating a different (wrong) package path

[image]

Comment: What happens when you uninstall and reinstall with `conda install -c anaconda opencv`?

Comment: Which pip are you using? You might be using one outside of your conda env. Make sure pip is installed in your env.

Comment: I think you are installing python3 opencv(due to 'cp37' in whl file) in python2 enviorment. Please install the python2 version.

Comment: Is that second path added in your `PATH` environment variable somehow?  That has caused issues with others (possible duplicate: [Anaconda does not use package from activated environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55089352/570918)). Please show the output from `import sys; sys.path`. This will show whether there is some global path where Python is sourcing imports.